# How can i pass as object as function parameter in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, object, parameters

I having Two class(ClassA,ClassB).From ClassB i have to call a method of ClassA while calling that method i have to pass my ClassB object and i need to receive it in ClassA.Method in ClassA is a static method.How can i pass an Object in a method?
if any one knows please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the reference of the ClassB by sending `self` as parameter to a method in ClassA.

```
[ClassA methodName:self];
```

In ClassA,

```
+(void)methodName:(ClassB*)param;
```